# Migrating SAP NetWeaver 7.0 project to 7.4

Tags: java, migration, e-commerce, netweaver

I'm migrating a SAP B2B Commerce project from version 7.0 to 7.4, with the previous version of java 1.4 to 1.7.

Right now I have no java errors, but this error messages in the JSP file:

```
//the import sap api couldn't not be resolved
<%@ page import="com.sap.isa.core.util.WebUtil" %>

<%@ page import="java.util.Iterator" %>
<%@ page import="java.math.BigDecimal" %>

//Can not find the tag library descriptor for "/isa"
<%@ taglib uri="/isa" prefix="isa" %>
```

I have been checking the web.xml files and turns out that there are references to a few `*.tld` files that are missing, those files  describe groups of custom tags with their name, implementation class, body content, attributes and variables.

I think that could be the problem but I'm not sure if those files were lost while the project was migrated to the newer version.
(Note: I didn't do that migration, I'm just fixing it to make it work again)

Any thoughts on this? I'm quite new to SAP applications and anything related to it.

**UPDATE**

It looks like a package/component is missing (com.sap.isa), [I have read a similar problem in this page](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/1836471), but since I don't have access permissions to download such component I can't try the solution, also I was told that before the migration, they didn't had such component (and the project worked) nor after the migration.

I've never been involved in the development, just in the migration of it, so I don't know many details of the configuration of it.

Comment: Are you using the NetWeaver Developer Studio to produce these errors?

Comment: Sorry, got pulled away prior to completing my comment...

There are a couple of considerations... When upgrading/migrating was the upgraded selection for the ISA in the same system (R/3 vs CRM) this would change the libraries for the supporting applications.  

Could reference: SAP R3 Internet sales or CRM internet sales which are mutually exclusive as far as I know.

Comment: @EricD yes i'm using net weaver dev studio. they are using crm internet sales

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@B.J.A.A.  Sorry for the delay... busy, busy.

I had a similar problem in an older version of NetWeaver. I found the errors were only in the studio.  If I published to our development/quality environment where the libraries existed, there were no operational errors.

In turn I had to find the API library and import it into NWDS for the errors to go away in the studio.  However, it seems you may have another issue to contend with as well.

from: https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3693074

> SAP ISA is available for 7.0x NetWeaver AND for 7.3x/7.4x Java
>   environments - BUT careful, you have to download different SCA files -
>   it is phyiscally not 100% same code as the code was migrated from 7.0x
>   to 7.3x and higher.

Scroll down past the "Correct Answer" there are several migration posts that may be helpful concerning the ISA functionality. But the result is the libraries are not the same from 7.0 to 7.3.

com.sap.ica resides in the SAPSHRJAV component.  The older links I have are no longer valid as SAP is overhauling much of their online resources. Once you get the library, run an import into your NWDS environment.

Some other links that may be helpful:

- https://blog.boris-wach.de/permalink/141
- https://help.sap.com/doc/javadocs_nw74_sps03/7.4.3/en-US/index.html

Hopefully this helps.  Good luck!

*edit*
Found where to download:

- go to the new SAP ONE Support Launchpad
- change the top drop-down to downloads
- enter "sapshrjav" into the search... you will get a list of various versions

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if you are kind enough to take a look  with my other question, greetings!

Comment: No problem.  I only have mobile access until Monday, I will take a look at it then.